# Слияние веток git с различными историями коммитов

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть вот такая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При попытке слить ветки patch-1 (зелёный) и CLang (тёмносиний) от мастера гитхаб выдаёт:

> There isn’t anything to compare.
>
> patch-1 and CLang are entirely different commit histories.

что вполне логично, так как ни мастер (красный) ни CLang (тёмносиний), ответвлённый от мастера, не являются ответвлением от предыдущего CLang (чёрный) или вообще какой-либо предыдущей ветки проекта, а значит и не могут иметь общую историю коммитов.

**Вопрос** - как всё-таки слить эти две ветки?

Comment: Как, в вашем понимании, должен выглядеть результат такого слияния?

Comment: Попробуйте привести минимальный пример. Воспроизведите похожую ситуацию во временном репозитории из пары файлов по паре строк и нескольких коммитов и выложите их сюда либо по-коммитно, либо через список команд для воспроизведения, вместе с желаемым результатом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь смержить две ветки, у которых нет общего предка. Git умеет это делать, но не позволяет, пока не убедится, что вы точно знаете, что вы делаете.

Если вы уверены, что вам необходимо мержить эти ветки, делайте так:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories patch-1 CLang
```

---

На всякий случай: подозреваю, что ветки появились из-за ошибки в рабочем процессе: ветка для разработки была перепутана с веткой для документации. Расскажу немного подробнее.

GitHub позволяет создавать сайты (называемые GitHub Pages), сопровождающие некоторый проект (репозиторий) или представляющие личную страницу пользователя. Один из вариантов хранения содержимого такого сайта — в общем репозитории проекта, но в "оторванной" (orphaned) ветке под именем `gh-pages`.

Вероятно, некто пытался настроить GitHub Pages и создал такую ветку. [Первый коммит этой ветки](https://github.com/BadAtom/Kidding/commit/5a2f3f0dff7355ce34afb840d9743462441fe9b9) содержит в себе шаблон страницы сайта. На графе это первый (левый) коммит красной ветки. После ветка master того же репозитория была переставлена на эту ветку и в ней продолжилась разработка. По приведённому в вопросе графу видно, что на пятом по счёту коммите от неё отошла ветка `CLang`.